# Webdev.Webserver40.exe crashes when using Code Contracts

Tags: c#, webdev.webserver

Sometimes when debugging with my application I encounter `Contract.Requires()` failing due to the condition its evaluating returning false (all good so far). However, if I click the Abort button webserver crashes and I get the message: "... has encountered a 
problem and needs to close ...". Two questions:

1. Is this the expected behaviour?
2. If not, what should be the behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to CodeContracts section in your project settings

[image]

And **uncheck** the "Assert on Contract Failure" checkbox in "Runtime checking" section

Comment: Thanks Dima, this avoids the problem by changing the default behaviour of Code Contracts from showing an Assert dialog to generating exceptions. So by doing this I can avoid the problem completely. However, it doesn't answer my question regarding the effect of Abort.